# AngularJS search using filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to search using angularjs filter method but its not working. I am not getting any errors in the console but still the search result is not showing up. Can someone help me on this.

This is my controller.js code:

```
.controller('SearchController', 
            [  
                '$scope', 
                'dataService', 
                '$location',
                '$routeParams',

                function ($scope, dataService, $location, $routeParams){
                    $scope.searchMovies = [ ];
                    $scope.searchCount = 0;

                    var getSearchResult = function (terms) {
                        dataService.getSearchResult(terms).then(
                            function (response) {
                                $scope.searchCount = response.rowCount + ' movies';
                                $scope.searchMovies = response.data;
                                $scope.showSuccessMessage = true;
                                $scope.successMessage = "All movie Success";
                            },
                            function (err){
                                $scope.status = 'Unable to load data ' + err;
                            }
                        );  // end of getStudents().then
                    };
                    if ($routeParams && $routeParams.term) {
                        console.log($routeParams.term);
                        getSearchResult($routeParams.term);
                    }

                }
            ]
        );
```

This is the services.js code:

```
this.getSearchResult = function (terms) {
            var defer = $q.defer(),
            data = {
                action: 'search',
                term: terms
            }
            $http.get(urlBase, {params: data, cache: true}).
                    success(function(response){
                        defer.resolve({
                            data: response.ResultSet.Result,
                            rowCount: response.RowCount
                        });
                    }).
                    error(function(err){
                        defer.reject(err);
                    });
            return defer.promise;
        };
```

This is my app.js code:

```
. when('/search', {
   templateUrl : 'js/partials/search.html',
   controller : 'SearchController'
}).
```

This is the search.html code:

```
<div>
<label>Search: <input ng-model="searchMovie"></label><br><br><br><br>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Category</th>       
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="search in searchMovies | filter:searchMovie">
            <td>
                {{search.title}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{search.description}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{search.name}}
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The search data is being retrieved from the database. I have tested the SQL and it works fine. Just thee problem is in the angularjs server side. Thank you.

Comment: @StarsSky i have added the html code in the question

Comment: hello, how do you set the url params? If they are not set, your searchMovies array will remain empty.

Comment: which url params u mean @Nora

Comment: Does this part get executed: `if ($routeParams && $routeParams.term) { console.log($routeParams.term); getSearchResult($routeParams.term); }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to give Alias for controller in your app.js file

```
 .when('/search', {
  templateUrl : 'js/partials/search.html',
  controller : 'SearchController'
  controllerAs: 'movies',
  });
```

Now After This in your search.html file pass controllerAs

```
<div>
<label>Search: <input ng-model="searchMovie"></label><br><br><br><br>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Category</th>       
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="search in searchMovies | filter:searchMovie">
        <td>
            {{movies.search.title}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{movies.search.description}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{movies.search.name}}
        </td>
    </tr>   
</tbody>
```